# Cannot use JSP property group configuration with jetty-runner 9.1.4

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, stripes

I'm trying to get a new development machine set up. I generally use jetty-runner to run my application `.war` file (it's a Stripes-based application).

I've got the latest version of jetty-runner (1.9.4), I think. When I try to run my `.war` file, I get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: __org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.JspPropertyGroupServlet__
```

I do in fact have a `<jsp-config>` block in my `web.xml`:

```
  <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
      <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/fw/taglibs.jsp</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
  </jsp-config>
```

If I comment that out, then I don't get the exception. I really want that prelude because I don't want to manually include it for every file. Of course, I'm doing that the way I've always done it, where "always" is a pretty long time here.

Is there some new way of doing that stuff for including a JSP prelude, or is there something wrong with my jetty-runner, or what?

*edit* — I didn't make it clear that I've been using a `web.xml` like this, with jetty-runner (older versions), for a long time. This is happening to me with the new jetty-runner version only (I haven't tried an old one but I will).

*another edit* — Version 7.6.15 does not throw that exception (on the same `.war` file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from the mailing list - credit Jan Bartel)

This is a bug we introduced with a change in 9.1.4 to preserve the
order of declaration of servlets and filters. Someone else has raised
a bug for it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433365

I've committed a fix to head:
https://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?id=e2ed934978b958d6fccb28a8a5d04768f7c0432d

This fix will be backported to an upcoming 9.1.5 release.

Comment: Yes thanks, I saw that on the list. So I might give 9.1.3 a try.  Thanks for posting here!